# How can I use a dynamic theme in ngx-skeleton-loader?

Tags: angular

The theme in my ngx-skeleton-loader is hardcoded:

```
<ngx-skeleton-loader [theme]="{ height: '20rem'}"></ngx-skeleton-loader>
```

I am trying to pass the theme dynamically. In my component I declare it as follows:

```
public theme = {height: '20rem'};
```

I tried to use the declared theme as a literal string as shown here but get an error:

```
<ngx-skeleton-loader [theme]=`${theme}`></ngx-skeleton-loader>
```

Answer (score 0):

What sort of error are you experiencing?

Instead of using string literals just use it in standard quotes.

```
<ngx-skeleton-loader [theme]="theme"></ngx-skeleton-loader>
```